# How can I access a variable outside of a function in Swift before it runs in a while loop?

Tags: swift, numerical-methods, swift-playground

First of all, try not to rip me to shreds :) I am relatively new to programming in general and this is my first question on StackOverflow!

This is hopefully a simple question, how can I return the "var m = ..." line outside of the function given below? I am trying to implement the Bisection Numerical Method (seen on rayweiderlich.com) but for a different equation. I am trying to access the variable outside of the function in order to update a label on a viewcontroller. Note: The iterative variable I am trying to solve does output correctly and that number is the 0.8789. Therefore, I think the algorithm is correct. Here is the tutorial link https://www.raywenderlich.com/99559/numeric-algorithms-using-playgrounds and my version of tutorials code:

```
    //: Playground - noun: a place where people can play

import UIKit

func bisection(x: Double) -> Double {

var lower = 0.0

var upper = x

let constant1 = Double((1+2*60))
let constant2 = Double(1+4*60)

var m = (constant1 - pow(constant2, 0.5)) / (2.0*60.0) //This returns the number I want (0.8789)

let epsilon = 1e-3

while (fabs(m * m - x) > epsilon) {


 m = (lower + upper)/2
    if m * m > x {
        upper = m
        print(m)
    } else {
        lower = m
        print(m)
    }

}

print(m)
return m //This returns the number I DON'T want (0.9995)
}

let bis = bisection(x: 1.0)

//somewhere around here is where I would like to use the "m" variable to update a label in a view controller
```

Comment: What's the point of the `while` loop and its update of `m` if you don't want the results of that loop?

Comment: I have been trying to figure that out as well and its driving me nuts!! Somehow it results in the correct iterative solution. If you change all the sixties to six you will get the iterative solution 0.666 which is also correct. Very odd to me...

Comment: What’s the equation that you’re trying instead?

Comment: Here is the equation I am trying to solve: X = (1+2*H*C) - sqrt(1+4*H*C)) / (2*H*C)                                                                        I want the value of "X" but I don't know the value of "H." The 0.87 that is outputting is definitely the correct answer for X.

Answer (score -1):

```
import UIKit

func bisection(x: Double) -> Double {

let constant1 = Double((1+2*60))
let constant2 = Double(1+4*60)

let m = (constant1 - pow(constant2, 0.5)) / (2.0*60.0)
return m
}

let bis = bisection(x: 1.0)
print(bis)
```

Is this what you want?

Comment: If this is a good solution (I don't know if it works), could you add some verbiage as to *why* it is? For somebody "new to programming" - or even for anyone else facing this same issue, an explanation of why this works might be as helpful as simply providing code that works.